# Excel VBA Target.Offset(#,#).Value Explained

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question regarding one piece of code form a sub I have in a workbook I am trying to use:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim firstCell As String

            On Error GoTo Done:

            If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Cancel = True
                ***firstCell = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value***
                If firstCell = "" Then GoTo Done:
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$D$1").Value = firstCell
            End If
    Done:
    End Sub
```

The part that confuses me the most are the values `(0,-2)` in the parenthesis of the `Target.Offset(0,-2)` expression. Can anyone explain what that snipit of code is doing in the sub?

Comment: Offset() uses row/column (RC) notation.  The first value is the row reference, and if it's +/- a row (in this case, zero indicates the existing row), and the column reference has a +/- (in this case, it's -2 columns, so if it'd D (4), it uses B (2)).  So it's saying that firstcell as a string is the text entered into the offset cell, taken from the Target.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/object-model-excel-vba-reference

Comment: @Cyril, so in other words, the value in cell F1, will be equal to the value in D1, and so on. Is that correct?

Comment: @anve firstcell = F1.Offset(0,-2).Value = D1.Value.  Short answer: Yes.

Comment: @anve Separate point... I regularly recommend getting used to using Cells() over Rane(), for a single cell.  Helps with consistency and in my opinion is easier to help with the VBA side of building.  Offset is Offset(rows,columns), Cells(rows,columns).  In the case of your code, you'd see *Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$D$1").Value = firstCell* becomes either *Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,4).Value = firstCell* or *Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,"D").Value = firstCell*, depending how you want to display.